# Service ‘memcached’ exited with status 139. Restarting. Messages (Couchbase)

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-bucket

I am facing below error most of time and at same time bucket appear down(1 node pending). This error facing just after setting up and Couchbase server even not accessed yet.

```
Service 'memcached' exited with status 139. Restarting. Messages:
2023-01-11T04:44:44.735996+00:00 CRITICAL     /opt/couchbase/bin/memcached(_ZN15google_breakpad16ExceptionHandler12GenerateDumpEPNS0_12CrashContextE+0x3ce) [0x400000+0x14fc5e]
2023-01-11T04:44:44.736000+00:00 CRITICAL     /opt/couchbase/bin/memcached(_ZN15google_breakpad16ExceptionHandler13SignalHandlerEiP9siginfo_tPv+0x94) [0x400000+0x14ff74]
2023-01-11T04:44:44.736009+00:00 CRITICAL     /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x7f67cce7e000+0x12b20]
2023-01-11T04:44:44.736015+00:00 CRITICAL     /opt/couchbase/bin/memcached() [0x400000+0xd3e93]
2023-01-11T04:44:44.736019+00:00 CRITICAL     /opt/couchbase/bin/memcached() [0x400000+0xa3e8c]
2023-01-11T04:44:44.736024+00:00 CRITICAL     /opt/couchbase/bin/../lib/libplatform_so.so.0.1.0(_ZN9Couchbase6Thread12thread_entryEv+0xf) [0x7f67cf6f2000+0x14e7f]
2023-01-11T04:44:44.736027+00:00 CRITICAL     /opt/couchbase/bin/../lib/libplatform_so.so.0.1.0() [0x7f67cf6f2000+0x95d7]
2023-01-11T04:44:44.736031+00:00 CRITICAL     /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x7f67cce7e000+0x814a]
2023-01-11T04:44:44.736061+00:00 CRITICAL     /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7f67ccabb000+0xfcf23] hide
```

[coubchbase bucket snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymAaS.png)

couchbase server details:

- Couchbase-server-community-6.6.0-7909
- Single Couchbase instance(no other cluster node)
- Installed on Operating System: CentOS Linux 8 (Core) ( Kernel: Linux 4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_64)
- Provided 10GB memory while setup the cluster (assigned 100MB to created bucket of type ephemeral)

Tried restart but not working and no such specific cause found in logs

Comment: I find an issue with a similar (but not identical) message that says log message suggest the customer has also encountered MB-41283, fixed in 6.6.1/7.0.0."

So you may wish to try one of those version.


I made the samecomment on your post to couchbase forums:
https://forums.couchbase.com/t/service-memcached-exited-with-status-139-restarting-messages/35311